# UniGUI components are messy when running the project

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

[image: Conception][image: Browser]
I am new to Delphi(10.4), and I am using Delphi [UniGUI](http://www.unigui.com/) Library to build a web client application.

My problem is that once I run the project on Google Chrome, I don't get the same result as what I did in the conception form, my modal form gets so messy, even the sizes of the components are not visually the same. If I try to fix them according to the result I am getting, it gets messier once I run the project.

Please refer to the two pictures as an example.

Does anybody know if I am missing something?
Thank you.

Comment: I suppose this might be obvious to some people, but to me it isn't clear what the "TUni Library" is. Could you please provide a link? It also isn't clear to me what you mean when you say that you "run the project on Google Chrome". A Win32 application isn't run in a browser. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand http://www.unigui.com/

Comment: Thank you @Dalija Prasnikar , this is exactly what i meant.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  Actually it is not a win32 desktop application , it is a web application , it may be a "responsive" issue , i am still looking for answers on the internet ..

Comment: You should post your question in UniGUI support forum at http://forums.unigui.com/.

Comment: If you find a solution, it would be good idea to post it as an answer to your own message so that other find it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better to learn about css in Unigui
see this video [Login form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IisgFEj8Yto)
it shows how css changes everything